# How to regularize an irregular curve?

Tags: functions, curves

I have a curve that has a couple of discontinuities and changes the sign ofd the 2nd derivative.

I want to fit this curve with a second curve, that have to be continuous and with positive 2nd derivative.

Are there known techniques to perform this?

I can not do hypotheses on the shape of the curve (such as exponential or linear)

Comment: Can you be more specific.  In general jump discontinuities are pretty easy to regularize while other kinds tend to involve so arbitrary decisions.  As for the 2nd derivative that would depend on what specifically you want to do.

Comment: In the first place, show us your curve, either using a picture, or giving parametrizations of its smooth parts.